# list identification and sorting: integers and strings

Tags: list, sorting

I have a list (i.e., list1) that features an integer then a set of strings (1 to 5 items), then a another integer and set of strings, etc. So the list looks like `[1, "biology", "physics", 2, "chemistry", "history", ...]`. I would like to loop through the list, id the first integer, assign it to a new list (i.e., list2), assign the strings to new list (i.e., list3), find the next integer assign it to list2, add the next strings to list3, etc.

So the final lists would be:

```
list1[1, "biology", "physics", 2, "chemistry", "history"...]
list2[1,2...]
list3["biology", "physics", "chemistry", "history"...]
```

Anyone have a code snippet to efficiently carry out this task?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: You could just create two empty lists (`list2`, `list3`), then loop over `list1` and check if element is number, append to `list2`, otherwise append to `list3`. Without knowing the language, impossible to say how it is coded.

Answer (score 0):

## List Partitioning

This is a pattern widely used in functional programming known as **partitioning** a list on a condition.

You start with an `iterable` and a predicate `pred`, and you want to obtain two lists, one for the items in `iterable` which match the predicate and another one with items that do not.

Assuming you are using Python you can filter the item that match the predicate from the others:

```
def partition(pred, iterable):
    return filter(pred, iterable), filter(lambda x: not pred(x), iterable)
```

You could also avoid iterating the iterable twice if it's big, scanning through all the items only once and append them to the corresponding list:

```
def partition(pred, iterable):
    match, nomatch = [], []
    for item in iterable:
        (match if pred(item) else nomatch).append(item)
    return match, nomatch
```

If you are using Python 3, `partition` is already included in `itertools` with the same syntax defined above so you just have to:

```
from itertools import partition
```

For your instance of list partitioning you would do:

```
list1 = [1, "biology", "physics", 2, "chemistry", "history"]
list2, list3 = partition(lambda obj: isinstance(obj, int), list1)
```